# Calculating recursively all possible List of positions on a board scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am trying to write a method, which, using a path and a dimension of a board, compute recursively the number of possible path that can travel through the board, once at each case.

For this I created the method : legal_moves(dim: Int, path : Path, x : Pos)
this method returns a list of all possible moves from position x on board of dimension dim that are not in the path yet.

info on types : type Pos = (Int,Int)
                type Path = List[Pos]

this methods works correctly.

Then I use the following recursive method to calculate all possible tours from a given path :

```
def count_tours(dim: Int, path : Path) : Int = {

  if (path.length == dim * dim) 1

  val x = for (m <- legal_moves(dim,path,path.head)) yield {

    count_tours(dim,m::path)
  }
  x.sum

}
```

But for some reasons, this function will only return 0

### Edit :

Example of input and output :

Let's say we have the 3 following positions : (0,0) (1,1) (1,2) and that in this case, a move allow us to travel between them as we want (e.g. : we can go from (0,0) to (1,1) but also from (0,0) to (1,2) etc ...

we can I call count_tours(dim,(0,0))
I want the output to be 2.

why ? we start from (0,0) (starting path) then we do : -> (1,1) -> (1,2) this is one path
or we can do (0,0) -> (1,2) -> (1,1) this is another path

2 possible paths so output is 2.

Comment: `if (path.length == dim * dim) 1` this line is useless. Did you forgot `return` ?  => `if (path.length == dim * dim) return 1`

Comment: I don't quite understand what are the "possible paths". How can you obtain the "possible paths" from one path? Please show some examples of input and output.

Comment: A path is when a List of positions contains all the possible positions from the board (line 1) I want to calculate how many of them are possible starting for the given path (which is incomplete, or if it is, then it is the only one)

Comment: see comment for example of input/output

Comment: Please also show the legal_moves method.

Comment: Your description and your code don't match. The list of legal moves should be different for every iteration. If it were the same there would be no point in calling `legal_moves()` with every recursion. And why are you interested if the path length matches the square of the board dimension? That might make sense if every path has to touch every square. And the reason the current code always returns `0` is because it only returns `x.sum` which can only be `0`. There is no other possible result.